# Opposite of binary_dilation

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function that does the opposite of `binary_dilation`?  I'm looking to remove 'islands' from an array of 0's and 1's.  That is, if a value of 1 in a 2D array doesn't have at least 1 adjacent neighbor that is also 1, its value gets set to 0 (rather than have its neighbor's values set equal to 1 as in `binary_dilation`).  So for example:

```
test = np.zeros((5,5))
test[1,1] = test[1,2] = test[3,3] = test[4,3] = test[0,3] = test[3,1] = 1

test
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

And the function I'm seeking would return:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Note the values changed in locations [0,3] and [3,1] from 1 to 0 because they have no adjacent neighbors with a value equal 1 (diagonal doesn't count as a neighbor).

Comment: As described this is not directly analogous to a binary erosion. You seem to actually be looking for a filter that looks for connected components (only orthogonal connectivity rather than diagonal as well) and eliminates components with area == 1. I would steer your search towards "connected component labeling" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mask with the cells to check and do a 2d convolution with `test` to identify the cells with `1`s adjacent to them. The logical and of the convolution and `test` should produce the desired output.

First define your mask. Since you are only looking for up/down and left/right adjacency, you want the following:

```
mask = np.ones((3, 3))
mask[1,1] = mask[0, 0] = mask[0, 2] = mask[2, 0] = mask[2, 2] = 0
print(mask)
#array([[0., 1., 0.],
#       [1., 0., 1.],
#       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

If you wanted to include diagonal elements, you'd simply update `mask` to include `1`s in the corners.

Now apply a 2d convolution of `test` with `mask`. This will multiply and add the values from the two matrices. With this mask, this will have the effect of returning the sum of all adjacent values for each cell.

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
print(convolve2d(test, mask, mode='same'))
#array([[0., 1., 2., 0., 1.],
#       [1., 1., 1., 2., 0.],
#       [0., 2., 1., 1., 0.],
#       [1., 0., 2., 1., 1.],
#       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

You have to specify `mode='same'` so the result is the same size as the first input (`test`). Notice that the two cells that you wanted to remove from `test` are `0` in the convolution output.

Finally do a element wise `and` operation with this output and `test` to find the desired cells:

```
res = np.logical_and(convolve2d(test, mask, mode='same'), test).astype(int)
print(res)
#array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

**Update**

For the last step, you could also just `clip` the values in the convolution between 0 and 1 and do an element wise multiplication.

```
res = convolve2d(test, mask, mode='same').clip(0, 1)*test
#array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
#       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
#       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```